# How do I calculate the space in between two glyphs in a TTF font?

Tags: truetype

This is a graph with definition of a [few terms for the horizontal glyph metrics for fonts](http://freetype.sourceforge.net/freetype2/docs/glyphs/Image3.png).

[image: Glyph metrics]

Let's say I have a sentence,

> Foo bar baz.

How do I get the spacing size, in pixels, between the words "Foo" and "bar"? I suppose I sum,

- The whitespace right-padding in the grapheme for 'o' in "Foo": subtract from the `advance` the `bearingX` + `width`
- The `advance` of the space character.
- The whitespace left-padding of the letter 'b' in "bar": simply `bearingX`.

Is this correct? What table has the bearingX?

Comment: I'm not much sure but we can read the font table using fonttools https://pypi.python.org/pypi/FontTools. I guess you will get each value of the font attributes in the table. you can calculate it from that table. :)

Comment: I'm not averse to that, I'm using [perl know.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22904518/124486) I just don't know what table it is in or what it is called.

Comment: @Even Carroll, Thanks, I haven't used perl. Even though in perl it seems to be there is font utils to read font table. Please see the link. 
http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=fontutils.

Comment: I linked to what I was using.

Comment: @EvenCarroll : Can not help, sorry for misguidance!

Comment: I asked a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42737846/true-type-font-format-pen-position-advance-width-and-kerning

Answer (score 4):

> How do I get the spacing size, in pixels, between the words "Foo" and "bar"?

You need to know the horizontal advance of the space character and kerning between "o" and " ", and between " " and b". I don't *think* you need bearingX to get the spacing. The result will be in font "units", defined by unitsPerEm of HEAD tag. So convert this result * font size / unitsPerEm, and you will get the spacing in "points". Then you will need to known, how many pixels there are in one point: depends on the application, could be your monitor DPI or Postscript's 72 dpi.

> What table has the bearingX?

bearingX is in also in HMTX, under "lsb" (left-side bearing) of longHorMetric (and also leftSideBearing, obviously).